# Handle text as elements, how to hide with CSS?

Tags: html, css, element

I have a div with content like this:

```
<div class="myDiv">
Here's some text that vary in length <span class="separator">/</span> Some other text <_other elements etc>
</div>
```

What I want is, only using CSS, to display the first text and hide the rest.

I have tried `.myDiv *:not(:first-child) { display: none; }` which hides all elements, except the first separator. All texts are still visible.

Is this even possible, only using CSS?

Edit: the text is in variable lenght, but this variation is restricted between 14 and 21 chars. It will never be line breaked. (Added this info for solutions like set the div to a width and visibility:hidden or solutions like that which is fully acceptable)

Comment: Given you can't select text nodes in CSS I don't think this will be possible without wrapping the text in some elements. There's a small typo in your example `<span class="separator">/<span>` is probably meant to be `<span class="separator">/</span>`.

Comment: Looks like your markup is wrong. Is that a nested span or a closing tag?

Comment: thanks! that was a typo. it's fixed now.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes: yea that's my problem, the text i want is not in a element. Therefore i was hoping for some clever walkaround but it seems like this is not possible.

Comment: @gubbfett Given your restrictions I'm trying to think of some hacky way this could be achieved with just CSS... coming up blank at the moment though.

Comment: one workaround would be to have the div in a width same as the first text and set it to overflow: hidden. the problem with that solution is to get that first text length. ;)

Comment: @gubbfett Yeah, if the first text was always going to be the same length that would be feasible, unfortunately as it is variable length you'd probably have to use JavaScript to calculate the width. Is it likely that the text will wrap onto a new line or will it always be on a single line?

Comment: @HiddenHobbes just one line. if i can't say (with CSS) "linebrak on each element". in that case, i would have my line on the first row - regarding to the css. :)

Comment: @gubbfett Forgive me if I've misunderstood but would this be suitable? https://jsfiddle.net/auwfwfd1/

Comment: @HiddenHobbes BRILLIANT! That is really clever! Cudos! Put that as an answer and we have a winner! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to directly select text nodes using CSS so the logical way of achieving this would be to wrap the text in an element and hide that. Unfortunately, this is not an option in this instance as the HTML markup cannot be modified and JavaScript cannot be used.

Luckily, we can rely on two things:

1. The text will always be on one line
2. The `.separator` element will exist

We can therefore use a combination of `overflow` on `.myDiv` and a pseudo element in `.separator` to forcibly hide the unwanted text:

- Add `height: 1em;` and `line-height: 1em;` to `.myDiv` to force it only to show one line of text
- Add `overflow: hidden;` to `.mDiv` to ensure that the overflown content is hidden
- Create an `:after` pseudo element in `.separator` and set it to `display: block;` to ensure that it is forced onto a new line. This will ensure that the separator itself (`/`) is still shown

```css
.myDiv {
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.separator:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">Here's some text that vary in length <span class="separator">/</span> Some other text
    <_other elements etc>
</div>
```

If the separator is not required the CSS can be simplified. The pseudo element can be removed and `.separator` itself can be set to `display: block;` to force it onto a new line.

```css
.myDiv {
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.separator {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">Here's some text that vary in length <span class="separator">/</span> Some other text
    <_other elements etc>
</div>
```

Comment: As a comment, this code leaves the / in the first <span> visible. I tried to set them to display none which makes the :after break. My simple solution to that was to add .separator { color: transparent; }

Comment: @gubbfett Apologies, I thought the separator was required, please see my updated answer. It means the CSS can be simplified a bit as the pseudo element is not needed.

Comment: @gubbfett No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it:

```
<div class="myDiv"><span>Here's some text that vary in length</span>  <span class="separator">/<span><span> Some other text </span><span><_other elements etc></span>
</div>

.myDiv > span:not(:first-child) {
    display:none;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/93pqrw08/)

Separate your text using `span` properly and then apply the *css* to hide the *spans* if its not the *first-child*

Comment: "Is this even possible, **only using CSS**?"

Comment: Yes, but that needs extra elements. In this case i have no possibilities to manipulate the markup, all I have access to is a CSS-file. Can't even use JS in this case :)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly CSS can only be applied to elements, not text nodes. Therefore with the provided html structure it cannot be done with only CSS. So I modified it so that in overall it works using only HTML and CSS :)

Comment: @gubbfett It is not possible without altering the html structure or using JS. This is the closest you could get to the result you are trying to achieve I guess

Comment: Yea i understand the solution and i really want to be able to alter the html. (If i could i would in this case don't even output the other elements in this case). :)

Comment: @gubbfett Can you tell me the overall context and what you are trying to achieve? We could discuss it on a chat if you like :)

Comment: @AhsN In this case it's a CMS with an extension that generates this markup. Of course i CAN alter the markup/extension but if the extension is upgraded sometime this will be overwritten.

Comment: @gubbfett Why not load your own JS code on the page to perform those modifications? If you add the load JS link in the extension itself, next time its updated, all you have to do is add the link back again

Comment: well, that's my next solution but i really don't want unless it's really necessary. which it seems to be. i was hoping for not using js. :)

Comment: @gubbfett Roger that :) Unfortunately CSS is not cut to do the job

Answer (score -1):

**Edited** You can Use this also

```
.myDiv{
 max-width: 28.5ch;
 overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

OR

```
<style>
.myDiv *:first-child
{
display:none;
}
</style>

<div class="myDiv">Here's some text that vary in length <span class="separator"> Some other text <_other elements etc></span>
```

Comment: This is not **only CSS**, it is **changing the markup** as well.

Comment: @connexo Yes, now check i **remove markup** and this is **only CSS**

Comment: that only hides the first element. the "separator". all texts are there. EDIT: i see now that the markup still is changed. the div contains [text] [element] [text] [element] etc, and i want to hide all except first [text]. [text] is plain text. not wrapped text.

Comment: @AmirIqbal The markup is still different from that used in the OP, you aren't closing the `.separator` `span` in the same place.

Comment: @gubbfett ok.. try this now .myDiv *:nth-child(n) { display:none;}.. its working.

Comment: @AmirIqbal .myDiv *:nth-child(n) still only goes for the elements. that is "wrapped stuff". plain texts are not treated as elements, and that is what i want to work around some how and/or be sure of is the case.